# Autocomplete appears behind modal form (bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, jquery, autocomplete, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My autocomplete is showing behind the bootstrap modal, which makes it impossible to pick a choice.

I have seen different post suggesting something like this, but it didnt work for me.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

and also (which is currently in my code)

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    appendTo : "#AddVenueFormModal",
    source: DataArray
});
```

None of these options have worked. Which makes me thing I probably made a typo somewhere.

I also checked if this had to do with my base template. I therefore removed it and added the bootstrap starter template to my html. This didn't work either.

**Html**

```
{% extends 'main/base.html'%}
{%load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'google_places_names.js' %}"></script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXX=places&callback=initAutocomplete""></script>
    
        <script>$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
            appendTo : "#AddVenueFormModal",
            source: DataArray
        });</scripts>
    

    </head>
{% block content %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href ="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddVenueFormModal" ><font size="3px" color="#008083">Can't find the venue?</font></a>

            
            <!--MODAL STARTS HERE-->
            <div class="modal" class="modal fade ui-front" tabindex="-1" id = "AddVenueFormModal">
                
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body ui-front">
                        <input id="autocomplete" style ="width: 500px "placeholder="Enter your address">
                        
                        <form id="venue_form" method="POST">

                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ venue_form}}
                    
                
                            <button type="submit" name="btnvenue_form" value="Submit" id="profile-btn">Validate</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--MODAL ENDS HERE-->
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

**.js file**

```
function initAutocomplete(){  
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocomplete"),{
    componentRestrictions: {'country':['uk']},
    fields: ['name','geometry','address_components'],
    types:['establishment','geocode']
  });

   autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post the answer to my problem:

I put it at the bottom of the block content.

```
<style>
    .modal-backdrop {
        z-index: 890;
    }
</style>
```